# Android - How to play/ preview .MOV video format using video view in android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

What are the ways to play .mov video formats in android application? Unfortunately, android does not support .mov video formats.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert it(no re-encoding) to mp4 container format by using FFMPEG tools in advance.